# Gson returns null for fromJson method

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to parse my `Tools` class using Gson. The problem is that the toolConverted have empty ToolA & ToolB when I run my unit test. The string itself is a valid JSON string, I figured the problem may be with my constructors in the Tools.java class.

Tools.java

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Tools{
    @JsonProperty("ToolA")
    List<ToolA> toolA;

    @JsonProperty("ToolB")
    List<ToolB> toolB;
}
```

ToolA.java

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ToolA{
    String uxA;
    String uxB;
    String uxC;
    String uxD;
}
```

Conversion

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
String toolsValue= jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(TOOLS_MAP);
Tools toolConverted = gson.fromJson(toolsValue, Tools .class);
```

toolsValue

```
{
   "ToolA":[
      {
         "uxA":"7",
         "uxB":"234.53",
         "uxC":"5345.23",
         "uxD":"0.155"
      }
   ],
   "ToolB":[
      {
         "state":"AZ",
         "compound_tax":"N",
         "federal_tax_percent":"5.0000",
         "provincial_tax_percent":"0.0000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `@SerializedName("ToolA")` instead of `@JsonProperty("ToolA")`, last one is a jackson annotation